# How can I paint on specific masked vertices even if they don't form faces?

Tags: masking, vertex-paint

I need to vertex-paint some models.  It would be very time-consuming to paint each vertex individually because I have lots of models that have lots of hidden vertices.  Instead, I am trying to select specific vertices from the UV map, then create vertex groups and masks from those vertex groups, and then mask only those vertices in vertex paint mode.  But I run into problems when I actually try painting the vertices:

[image]

I'm trying to paint these vertices.  Notice they do not form any faces.

Older documentation for Blender (the newest I could find) says "By default, when you paint, the paint color spreads to all faces connected to the vertice..."  I would like that behavior enabled.  I just want to put a vertex color on the vertices, and then have that color bleed onto the adjacent faces evenly, like the documentation says.

Instead, it seems I can only paint on faces, not on individual vertices.  Is there a way to paint on an individual vertex, even if there are no faces to be seen while painting?